# Stopping R from appending .1, etc as suffix on header character vectors when called using colnames

Tags: r

I am trying to return a dataframe containing all of the values in each column that are less than -1.5 that has both the column header and the rowname. I basically have everything worked out, except in the final step where I replace a column that has the column numbers with the corresponding column names from the original dataframe when there are multiple values from the same column that are less than -1.5 the new column name values are listed as "column name.1". I have searched around and found out that make.unique appears to do a similar thing, but I never called that function.

```
A <- c(0.6, -0.5, 0.1, 1.6, -1.6, 0.4, -1.6)
B <- c(0.7, -2.1, -0.3, 1.1, 2.1, -1.7, 1.1)
DF <- as.data.frame(cbind(A, B))
colnames(DF) <- c("010302A620300302000", "010803A110100069000")
rownames(DF) <- c("1996", "1997", "1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002")
```

So my original dataframe looks something like this:

```
010302A620300302000 010803A110100069000
1996                 0.6                 0.7
1997                -0.5                -2.1
1998                 0.1                -0.3
1999                 1.6                 1.1
2000                -1.6                 2.1
2001                 0.4                -1.7
2002                -1.6                 1.1
```

In order to get the relevant values for each row:

```
DF.new <- as.data.frame(which(DF <= -1.5, arr.ind = T, useNames = TRUE))
DF.new <- as.data.frame(setDT(DF.new, keep.rownames = TRUE)[])

DF.new$SUID <- colnames(DF[, DF.new[ ,3]])
```

This brings me to the problem, how do I use the colnames function so that the resulting SUID column does not append ".1" to repeat character vectors like I see here:

```
    rn row col                  SUID
1 2000   5   1   010302A620300302000
2 2002   7   1   010302A620300302000.1
3 1997   2   2   010803A110100069000
4 2001   6   2   010803A110100069000.1
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Generally, it's inadvisable to use `as.data.frame`. Usually better to just use `data.frame` and (OMG!) STOP using `cbind` inside either of those functions. BAD DOG. Or perhaps? BAD Teacher?

Comment: Talk about turgid code. Putting `setDT(...)` inside as.dataframe is rather convoluted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subset your column names from a character vector rather than columns from a new data frame.

like this

```
DF.new$SUID <- colnames(DF)[DF.new[ ,3]]
```

instead of this

```
DF.new$SUID <- colnames(DF[, DF.new[ ,3]])
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I knew it must be a quick fix

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty fix is `DF.new$SUID <- floor(DF.new$SUID)` to remove the decimals.

Comment: I immediately thought the same thing but because characters and integers are mixed this won’t work